# How to cast on roku using Google chromecast library in Android

Tags: android, casting, google-cast, roku

In Android I am using Google Casting Library. Google Casting Library is not able to detect the Roku and Firetv Devices. I want the Google Cast Library to be able to detect roku and firetv devices.
YouTube Casting detect all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cast SDK can only detect genuine cast devices. In order to discover other types of devices, you need to [write your own](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate#how_session_management_works) "Session" provider and discovery mechanism; various devices provide different mechanisms and protocols for discovery and there is no one global approach that all use.

Comment: Thanks Ali Naddaf Sir. Can you help me how to start building my own cast service for roku and fire tv. I need your help.

Comment: Follow the link that I have in my answer and read out docs and tutorials on Cast SDK v3.

Comment: Hello Ali Naddaf Sir. Sorry for disturbing you again. I have gone through the article. I have integrated Google chromecast v3 into my app. How to make my app discover roku and firet. I am a newbee and you are the only source of help. I am not able to understand how to start for roku and firetv. I have integrated chromecast v3 into my app successfully. I am totally confused how to do it with roku and firetv.

Comment: I have no knowledge of Roku or FireTv to help you with their discovery; you might want to ask on the respective forums of those product to see what discovery mechanisms (usually either mDNS or SSDP or sometimes proprietary) can be used for those products.

Comment: @AliNaddaf, I'm a colleague of Piyush. We were able to write the session providers for Roku and FireTV successfully. What we need to do now is, we need to show the available Roku/FireTV devices in the list of devices (dialog). For that, we could append to the list (in the dialog) which is prepared by cast SDK or we could get the "genuine cast devices" from cast SDK and create our own list dialog.

What do you suggest. And how could we get the list of "genuine cast devices"?

Comment: I suggest appending that to the same dialog; that is the whole point of implementing session providers, etc.

Comment: @AliNaddaf, do we have the access to that dialog? How can we append an item to that dialog?

Comment: Hello Ali Naddaf sir. Thanks for helping. We have almost completed our goal. Only one thing left. Just wanted to know How to show the chromecast icon on toolbar even if there are no chromecast devices.

Comment: You are not supposed to show the cast icon if there are no eligible cast devices, see the UX guidelines.

Comment: @AliNaddaf Hello Sir. Your help is needed. I have given queueload to remote media client which is playing my playlist .I want to capture the event whenever there is a failure in between  to load a media url in a queue. How to achieve this.

Comment: @AliNaddaf Please help and share some solution if possible.

Comment: If you want to capture errors and do something based on your requirements, you'd need to write a custom receiver.

Comment: I just want to capture any error when playing queue on Chromecast. Is there any existing  callback. Also I need to know how to customize UI of ExpandedControlActivity

Comment: @AliNaddaf. Just Need your Help. My Application in between casting the video for several minutes suddenly calling On session ended giving 2005 error code unepexectedly. Please help how to resolve this.

Comment: I am using   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:10.2.0 for above question. Please help @AliNaddaf